# how to add .apk and sqlite database file in android mobile?

Tags: java, android

My application is developed now & i want to test it on mobile phone. I want to add .apk & .sqlite file into an android mobile. but i dont get a specific solution for it. pls tell me an solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: If you have developed application by eclipse, then you can directly run that application on your mobile, i don't have any idea of other IDEs,attach your mobile with system and by using Run configuration you can directly run that application to your phone. 
2: Transfer your apk file to your mobile by connecting your device with system and install the apk.

Answer (score 1):

You need only .apk. You can upload it anywhere (for example ftp), send it by mail and open it from your android. Or you can put it in sdcard and install it using Astra app.

Answer (score 0):

Lars Vogel has written a very good tutorial on android stuff, including how to deploy on mobile:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#deployondevice